# PHP add a logo to existing PDF that stored in database (MySQL)

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I am doing a basic system that the staff uploads a pdf file with some description and this data stored in database MySQL.

The admin will view this pdf and click on approval if everything is ok.

An image will be inserted in pdf file with approve logo.

I use fpdf and fpdi class to do this, I manage to do this if PDF file stored on the actual path as shown in the code below.

```
<?php

use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi2/src/autoload.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new Fpdi();
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set the source file
$pdf->setSourceFile('PdfDocument.pdf');
// import page 1
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
// use the imported page and place it at position 10,10 with a width of 100 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);

// now write some text above the imported page
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
$pdf->Write(0, 'This is just a simple text');

$pdf->Output();
```

BUT when I try to use $pdf->setSourceFile($string) or other that actual file for example (PDF $content from string (database) or URL) I cannot manage to do that.

```
    // set the source file
//$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile("http://localhost/pdf/getpicture.php?fid=2");

$stream = fopen('data:text/plain,' . urlencode("http://localhost/pdf/getPDF.php?fid=2"), 'rb');
//$reader = new SetaPDF_Core_Reader_Stream($stream);
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($stream);
```

My question is how can I import PDF from MySQL string to be edited by fpdf and fpdi or any other free PDF classes.

Note: I try to use stream_wrapper_register with no luck so far. as in this link
https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/miscellaneous/using-a-pdf-from-a-php-variable-instead-of-a-file/

Please help me with a simple example as I am not really familiar with PDF classes.

Thank you.

Comment: `$stream = "http://localhost/pdf/getPDF.php?fid=2";` (??)

Comment: Consider not to store binary data into the database. Just store the filepath into the database and put the file on disk.

Answer (score 0):

I think the source of your trouble is in the line:

```
$stream = fopen('data:text/plain,' . urlencode("http://localhost/pdf/getPDF.php?fid=2"), 'rb');
```

PHP's fopen function returns a file pointer, and is not giving you the name of the PDF file you want.

So later when you call

```
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($stream);
```

$stream is not a string with a PDF filename.

If your http://localhost/pdf/getPDF.php?fid=2 URL is returning the filename of the PDF, try getting that value with file_get_contents like so:

```
$pdf_file = file_get_contents('http://localhost/pdf/getPDF.php?fid=2');
```

and then call

```
$pdf->setSourceFile($pdf_file);
```

Comment: `setSourceFile()` doesn't accept a PDF as a string. So this answer is missleading and faulty.

Comment: Well, I didn't test this code, so @JanSlabon may be right. If he is, then the documentation [here](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/the-fpdi-class/#c_setasignFpdiFpdiTraitsetSourceFile) is wrong. It says the $file argument may be on of the following: 
Path to the file or a stream resource or a StreamReader instance.

Comment: What's wrong with the documentation? You try to pass the PDF content as a string which is not documented.

Comment: @JanSlabon, I think there is a miscommunication. I was not saying to pass the content of the PDF as a string, but the filename of the PDF as a string. If that does not work with setSourceFile(), then the documentation is misleading.

Comment: Ok, understood. But this doesn't make sense at all... calling a script on the same host, to get a path to a local file on the same host is absolutely nonsense :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use an additional HTTP request to access a file from a database!

FPDI 2 allows you to read from any source through a `StreamReader` class:

```
// use a resource
$fh = fopen('a/path/to/a.pdf', 'rb');
$pdf->setSourceFile(new StreamReader($fh));
// same as
$pdf->setSourceFile($fh);
// don't forget to call fclose($fh);

// use a path
$path = 'a/path/to/a.pdf';
$pdf->setSourceFile(StreamReader::createByFile($path));
// same as
$pdf->setSourceFile($path);

// use a string
$pdfString = '%%PDF-1.4...';
$pdf->setSourceFile(StreamReader::createByString($pdfString));
```

So do not call an external script but query your database for the PDF and pass it e.g. as a string.

PS: [You cannot edit a PDF with FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/can-i-edit-a-pdf-document-with-fpdi/#question-82)!

Comment: Thank @Jan Slabon for you suggestion.

I try to follow your code but I got this error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'StreamReader' not found in..

My full code as below

`use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
use setasign\Fpdi\PdfReader;

require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi2/src/autoload.php');
require_once('fpdi2/src/PdfReader/PdfReader.php');

// use a resource
$fh = fopen('http://localhost/pdf/invoice2.pdf', 'rb');
$pdf->setSourceFile(new StreamReader($fh)); `

May you help me with full example 
I am very sorry I am new to PHP programing 

Thank you

Comment: Add a `use setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\StreamReader;` to your use statements (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) for more details). Additionally: DO NOT USE AN HTTP REQUEST TO ACCESS A LOCAL FILE! If you really need to access an external file, you have to download it first and pass it as a string (last example).

Comment: I got this error after I added `use setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\StreamReader;`

This error
`Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Given stream is not seekable! in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf\fpdi2\src\PdfParser\StreamReader.php:112 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf\fpdi.php(20): setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\StreamReader->__construct(Resource id #10) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf\fpdi2\src\PdfParser\StreamReader.php on line 112`

Comment: I already answered this: "If you really need to access an external file, you have to download it first and pass it as a string (last example)."